# select mysql from a row limit and asc php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a table like below

```
ID
1
2
3
4
5
```

I want to select ID `2` then ASC LIMIT 3. I want to get `2,3,4`.

My select goes.

`SELECT * FROM TABLEID WHERE ID = 2 AND status = 'unuse' ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 3`

But I only get `1` record I am expecting `3` row to be returned base on the `LIMIT 3`

Comment: _“I am expecting 3 row to be returned base on the LIMIT 3”_ - you are expecting wrong, because LIMIT can not create records that aren’t there to begin with. You have only one record with ID=2, so a WHERE clause selecting those records of course only returns this one. You want `WHERE ID >= 2`

Comment: @CBroe I am expecting to make the `ID=2` as anchor to start the where clause then use ASC to get the greater value. Now I realize you are correct and it was very simple. Can you provide it as answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am expecting 3 row to be returned base on the LIMIT 3

You are expecting wrong, because LIMIT can not create records that aren’t there to begin with. You have only one record with ID=2, so a WHERE clause selecting those records of course only returns this one.

You want `WHERE ID >= 2` to first select all records that have an id 2 or greater, and then limit that selection to 3 records only.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEID WHERE ID BETWEEN 2 AND 4
```

OR exclude the id

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEID WHERE ID >=2 status = 'unuse' AND id <> 1 ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: the from is static but the to is not i only base it on limit like limit 3

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from TABLED limit 1,4
```

1 is offset start point 
4 is upto count point